# Concatenate array with new array created in for loop python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, concatenation

I have the following type of data, I am doing predictions:

```
Input: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
       1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
       1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

Output: 6
        7
        8
```

I want to predict one at a time and feed it back to the input as the value for the last column. I use this function but it is not working well:

```
def moving_window(num_future_pred):
    preds_moving = []
    moving_test_window = [test_X[0,:].tolist()]
    moving_test_window = np.array(moving_test_window)
    for j in range(1, len(test_Y)):
        moving_test_window = [test_X[j,:].tolist()]
        moving_test_window = np.array(moving_test_window)
        pred_one_step = model.predict(moving_test_window[:,:,:])
        preds_moving.append(pred_one_step[0,0])
        pred_one_step = pred_one_step.reshape((1,1,1))
        moving_test_window = 
        np.concatenate((moving_test_window[:,:4,:], pred_one_step), axis= 1)
    return preds_moving

preds_moving = moving_window(len(test_Y))
```

What I want:

```
Input: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
       1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 6
       1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 17

Output: 6
        17
        18
```

Basically to make the first prediction `[1,2,3,4,5] --> 6` and then remove the last column `[5]` from the next inputs and add the predicted value at each time.

What it does now, it just takes all the inputs as they are and makes predictions for each row. Any idea appreciated!